# How to specify amount of side by side plots on one window

Tags: r, ggplot2, split

Let's consider four graphs following :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
set.seed(42)
vec_1 <- rnorm(100)
vec_2 <- runif(100)
vec_3 <- rexp(100)
vec_4 <- rpois(100,1)


plot_1 <- ggplot()+aes(x=1:length(vec_1), y= vec_1) + geom_line() + xlab(NULL) + ylab('Norm')
plot_2 <- ggplot()+aes(x=1:length(vec_2), y= vec_2) + geom_line() + xlab(NULL) + ylab('Unif')
plot_3 <- ggplot()+aes(x=1:length(vec_3), y= vec_3) + geom_line() + xlab(NULL) + ylab('Exp')
plot_4 <- ggplot()+aes(x=1:length(vec_4), y= vec_4) + geom_line() + xlab(NULL) + ylab('Poiss')
```

Now - How can I specify amount of plots in one window ? For example I want to have 2 side by side plots containing 2 plots. i.e.

```
plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2)
```

[image]

```
plot_grid(plot_3, plot_4)
```

[image]

It's very easy to make, but - is there any possibly how can do it by one command ? I tried for example

```
plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, ncol = 2, nrow = 1),
```

but it's just truncating remaining plots. In other words - I'm looking for a solution in which I can provide all four graphs, and it will divide them into 2 side by side graphs containing 2 plots. I want solution like this because it would simplify a lot of things in complicated function I'm coding.

**About facet_grid() function**

I was trying to use it, however If I want to have same result as above (i.e. two times two side by side plots containing two graphs) I used :

```
data = data.frame(
  x = rep(seq_along(vec_1), 4),
  y = c(vec_1, vec_2, vec_3, vec_4),
  dist = rep(c('normal', 'uniform', 'exponential', 'poisson'), each = length(vec_1))
)

ggplot(data) +
  aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ dist, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

I want to obtain two graphs containing two side by side plots in one rows and 2 cols (just like I presented with `plot_grid()`), however I get error : `Error: The given dimensions cannot hold all panels. Please increase` ncol`or`nrow

**EDIT**

I tried to run a function plot_grids() on data following :

```
plot_grids(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, plot_4, plot_4, ncol = 3L, nrow = 2L)
```

But I get these warnings :

```
45: In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
46: In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class waiver into a grob.
47: In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
48: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class ScalesListggprotogg into a grob.
49: In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class uneval into a grob.
50: In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
```

**EDIT**

Now I'm trying to adjust code to be compatible with incorrect number of dimensions i.e. If for example we have 6 graphs to plot and we specify ncol = 2 and nrow = 2 I want to get two side by side plots. One the first one I want to have four plots and on the second one I want to have remaining two. I tried to do it by adding empty plots if needed :

```
plot_grids = function (plotlist = NULL, nrow, ncol) {
  plots_per_fig = nrow * ncol
  if (length(plotlist) %% plots_per_fig !=0) {
    df <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:(length(plotlist) %% plots_per_fig)) {
      plotlist[[(length(plotlist)+i)]] <- ggplot(df)
    }
  }
  num_figs = length(plotlist) / plots_per_fig
  groups = if (num_figs == 1) list(plotlist)
  else unname(split(plotlist, cut(seq_along(plotlist), num_figs)))
  
  plot_grid_wrapper = function (plotlist) {
    do.call(
      cowplot::plot_grid,
      c(list(plotlist = plotlist, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol))
    )
  }
  lapply(groups, plot_grid_wrapper)
}
```

However, this code

```
plot_grids(plotlist=list(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, plot_4, plot_4), ncol = 2L, nrow = 2L)
```

gives me only partialy proper result :

First image :

[image]

Second image :

[image]

Everything would be great if there was a two not empty graphs on second image, instead of one. Do you have any idea why it's occurs ?

Answer (score 2):

`plot_grid` always generates a single plot. You can wrap it into a straightforward function to extend it to generate multiple plots:

```
#' Arrange plots into multiple grids
#'
#' \code{plot_grids} extends \code{\link[cowplot]{plot_grid}} by generating a list
#' of multiple grids of plots.
#'
#' @param ... list of plots
#' @param plotlist optional plots as a list
#' @param nrow number of rows of plots per grid
#' @param ncol number of colums of plots per grid
#' @param plot_grid_args named vector of further arguments to pass to
#'   \code{\link[cowplot]{plot_grid}}
#' @return \code{plot_grids} returns a list of plots, each generated by
#'   \code{\link[cowplot]{plot_grid}} with a subset of the plots passed via
#'   \code{...} or \code{plotlist}.
plot_grids = function (..., plotlist = NULL, nrow, ncol, plot_grid_args = NULL) {
    plots = c(list(...), plotlist)
    plots_per_fig = nrow * ncol
    num_figs = length(plots) / plots_per_fig
    groups = if (num_figs == 1L) list(plots)
        else unname(split(plots, cut(seq_along(plots), num_figs)))

    plot_grid_wrapper = function (plotlist) {
        do.call(
            cowplot::plot_grid,
            c(list(plotlist = plotlist, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol), plot_grid_args)
        )
    }
    lapply(groups, plot_grid_wrapper)
}
```

And then,

```
figs = plot_grids(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3, plot_4, ncol = 2L, nrow = 1L)
```

Comment: that function basically exists already with patchwork::wrap_plots, which take ggplot objects as a list

Comment: @tjebo Does `wrap_plots` generate a *list* of plots? As far as I understand it always generates a single plot, sample as `plot_grid`. That said, the shout-out to ‘patchwork’ is good: I believe it essentially supersedes ‘cowplot’ for the purpose of arranging plots. But I don’t really use either so I’m no expert.

Comment: You're right, sorry I think I misunderstood the OP and then also misread your function :) I personally prefer patchwork, but cowplot has its merits.

Comment: That's a pretty good code, but why If I have ncol = 2, and nrow = 2 I see error invalid number of intervals  ? I think it should just plot everything on one plot, am I right ?

Comment: @John Yes, I didn’t account for that case because then you can just call `plot_grid`, right? Fixed now.

Comment: Hmm, I adjusted my question. I'm not sure if I did something incorrectly with your code

Comment: @John Yes, that was a bug in my changed code, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: Wow that's a really good code! It will help me tremendously ;)) I just have one more question. Do you think is this possible to do splitting to side by side plots even when dimensions are not correct ? I.e. for example if we have 6 plots and we specify nol = 2 and nrow = 2. It would be wonderful to have 4 plots on the first image and 2 plots on the second one (now we have warning about incorrect dimension)

Answer (score 0):

1. Combine data into table:

   ```
   vecs = list(vec_1, vec_2, vec_3, vec_4)
   data = data.frame(
       x = unlist(lapply(lengths(vecs), seq)),
       y = unlist(vecs),
       dist = rep(c('normal', 'uniform', 'exponential', 'poisson'), times = lengths(vecs))
   )
   ```
2. Plot it:

   ```
   ggplot(data) +
       aes(x = x, y = y) +
       geom_line() +
       facet_wrap(~ dist, ncol = 2L)
   ```

And if you want your plot to include only some of the data, filter it before passing it to `ggplot2` (I’m using `filter` from ‘dplyr’ for this, but any method works):

```
data %>%
    filter(dist %in% c('normal', 'uniform')) %>%
    ggplot() + aes(x = x, y = y) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ dist, ncol = 2L)
```

To get separate *y*-axes, and labels at the side rather than at the top, you can modify the `facet_wrap` call as follows:

```
facet_wrap(~ dist, ncol = 2L, strip.position = 'left', scales = 'free') +
ylab('')
```

To change the look of the facet strip label, you can [use the `strip.*` options of the `theme` function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html). To get pretty much the same look as your screenshot, use

```
theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
    strip.placement = 'outside'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Konrad, however your code plots all four plots together, and that's not exactly what I was looking for. Please have a look at my updated question for more details.

Comment: @John I don’t really understand the problem: my code produces exactly the same arrangement as in your screenshot. The only difference is the *order* of the plots, which can be specified by making `dist` an ordered factor.

Comment: Not exactly the same one - you have one plot containing four plots, and I have two plots containing two plots ;))

Comment: @John OK, that’s not visible from the screenshot. ;-) But OK, that’s easy enough to accomplish, just `filter` the data before passing it to `ggplot`. See updated answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, I changed a little bit look of the screenshot to make it more visible ;)) Could you please show me exactly what you mean by filtering data before passing it to ggplot ? I'm not sure how it would help in my problem.

Comment: Okay so you plot only two of the graphs - normal and uniform. But my question was more - how can I have two side by side plots containing two plots using only ONE command.

Comment: Because your solution is more or less identicall to plot_grid(), but it doesn't provide possibility to split plots into several side by side plots.

Comment: @John I see. I don’t think such a function exists, all these functions *combine* plots, i.e. their whole purpose is to produce a single plot, not multiple ones. Of course you could simply write your own function that takes, say, four plots and calls `plot_grid` twice internally.

Comment: @John See my second answer. I’ll leave this here since it might helpful to others (and it provides an, as I find, superior solution to `plot_grid` for this problem), but it answers a different question.